# Linq to SQL ADD and Update

Tags: winforms, linq

As you can tell from my code, I'm absolute a beginner.  After searching through other similar issues on LINQ to SQL problems, I find myself still seemingly stuck on two objectives.  1) Adding a new entry with input from the user selection from three comboboxes and a datepicker and 2) Updating an existing database entry using interactions from the datagridview.

My windows form datagridview is displaying the following output

```
**select b.Date, a.EmployeeName, 
       c.ProjectName, b.Hours
from  dbo.Employees a
left outer join dbo.EmployeeProjectHours b
    on a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
left outer join dbo.Projects c
    on b.ProjectId = c.ProjectId**
```

Here is my ADD method the user is providing me with ProjectName, EmployeeName, Date and Hours.  Any thoughts for a layman would be appreciated.

I don't get an error running the insert, but nothing is added to my dab as well

```
     using (ProjectHoursDataContext dbInsert = new ProjectHoursDataContext())
     {
        this.Validate();

        EmployeeProjectHour empHours = new EmployeeProjectHour();

        empHours.Date = dateDateTimePicker.Value;
        empHours.Hours = Convert.ToDecimal(hoursComboBox.Text);
        empHours.ProjectId = dbInsert.Projects.First(p => p.ProjectName == projectNameComboBox.Text).ProjectId;
        empHours.EmployeeId = dbInsert.Employees.First(m => m.EmployeeName == employeeNameComboBox.Text).EmployeeId;

        db.EmployeeProjectHours.InsertOnSubmit(empHours);
        dbInsert.SubmitChanges();

     }
```

Here is my Update attempting to use updates directly from the datagridview.  I get the following error: *A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll*

```
     using (ProjectHoursDataContext dbUpdate = new ProjectHoursDataContext())
     {
        this.Validate();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        projectBindingSource.DataSource = dbUpdate;
        projectBindingSource.DataMember = "Updates";

        projectBindingSource.EndEdit();
        dbUpdate.SubmitChanges();
     }
```

Comment: Looks like you're getting an existing `employee id ` first and then setting your new `employeeId` to that value. Is `EmployeeID` a primary key? Identity?

Comment: Yes, EmployeeID is a primary key.  The EmployeeName combobox, I am restricting to only choose from existing employees, which is why I'm setting the employeeID to match what is already in the db for the selected employee.  I'm guessing my format is incorrect or is it a matter of the order I set things?

Comment: So are you trying to add projects to an existing employee? Or it looks more like there are existing `Employee` `Project` and `EmployeeProjectHours` records and you are supposed to edit them?

Comment: Yes.  And after you wrote that, I realized I needed to comment out everything except the InsertOnSubmit for EmployeeProjectHours. But I still get an exception thrown when I SubmitChanges:

Comment: Did you see my answer? Did you try the code from there?

Comment: So after careful consideration of what you said earlier, I realized (foolishly) that I shouldn't be inserting anything to the Employees or Projects folder.  These tables contain EmployeeName, EmployeeID and ProjectName and ProjectID, which is what I will need to map to for reference to the EmployeeProjectHours to display in the datagridview (how many projects and employee has for however many hours each).  I'm not getting an error anywhere, but somehow, nothing is still being written in to my database.  I've even set the Identity Increment to yes/1. I'll paste the code below. Thanks so much

Comment: Not sure I get you completely. You can edit your question to update it with newer code. Does it work or not? And mainly, what are you trying to do? Edit existing data or create new records?

Comment: Your code didn't work for me.  No error was thrown, but nothing added to the dab as well.  I've reposted my question as well as my updated code.  I'm sorry to be such a pain.

Comment: Where is your database located? In the App_Data or in the `\bin`. Check if you have multiple copies and possibly the one in your bin is being created when you build your application.

Answer (score 0):

My best **guess** so far is, you want to edit and change existing `Employee`, `Project` and `EmployeeProjectHours` records.

So you would do:

```
 using (ProjectHoursDataContext dbInsert = new ProjectHoursDataContext())
 {
    this.Validate();

    // Get the records
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    Project proj = new Project();
    EmployeeProjectHour empHours = new EmployeeProjectHour();

    // Set new values to Employees tables
    emp = dbInsert.Employees
       .First(m => m.EmployeeName == employeeNameComboBox.Text);
    //just get the empployee

    //setting values will update it    
    emp.EmployeeName = employeeNameComboBox.Text;

    // GET an existing project
    proj = dbInsert.Projects
                  .First(p => p.ProjectName == projectNameComboBox.Text);

    //update its values.  
    proj.ProjectName = projectNameComboBox.Text;
    proj.ProjectDescription = "Test";

    //GET an empHours
     empHours = dbInsert.Projects.First(p => p.EmployeeId == emp.EmployeeId && 
                          p.ProjectId == proj.ProjectId);
    //set its values
    empHours.Date = dateDateTimePicker.Value;
    empHours.Hours = Convert.ToDecimal(hoursComboBox.Text);

    dbInsert.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

Comment: using (ProjectHoursDataContext dbInsert = new ProjectHoursDataContext())
         {
            this.Validate();

            EmployeeProjectHour empHours = new EmployeeProjectHour();

            empHours.Date = dateDateTimePicker.Value;
            empHours.Hours = Convert.ToDecimal(hoursComboBox.Text);
            empHours.ProjectId = dbInsert.Projects.First(p => p.ProjectName == projectNameComboBox.Text).ProjectId;
            empHours.EmployeeId = dbInsert.Employees.First(m => m.EmployeeName == employeeNameComboBox.Text).EmployeeId;

            dbInsert.SubmitChanges();

         }

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the new code below, I also set my increment status for my projects database to NO.  I had set it yes from a previous stackoverflow discussion.  Thanks

```
  public void AddInfo()
  {
     db.Connection.Open();

        this.Validate();

        EmployeeProjectHour empHours = new EmployeeProjectHour();

        empHours.Date = dateDateTimePicker.Value;
        empHours.Hours = Convert.ToDecimal(hoursComboBox.Text);
        empHours.ProjectId = db.Projects.First(p => p.ProjectName == projectNameComboBox.Text).ProjectId;
        empHours.EmployeeId = db.Employees.First(m => m.EmployeeName == employeeNameComboBox.Text).EmployeeId;

        db.EmployeeProjectHours.InsertOnSubmit(empHours);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        db.Connection.Close();

  }
```